# Take ScreenShot without Window

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

I've been studying Son Of Grab Apple demo and I'm really struggling to get a screenshot of screen without any window (only desktop, dock and menu bar). Does anyone knows how to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some example code which takes a screenshot with just the desktop.

```
CFArrayRef onScreenWindows = CGWindowListCreate(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
CFArrayRef nonDesktopElements = CGWindowListCreate(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly | kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements, kCGNullWindowID);
CFRange range = CFRangeMake(0, CFArrayGetCount(nonDesktopElements));
CFMutableArrayRef desktopElements = CFArrayCreateMutableCopy(NULL, 0, onScreenWindows);
for (int i = CFArrayGetCount(desktopElements) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    CGWindowID window = (CGWindowID)(uintptr_t)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(desktopElements, i);
    if (CFArrayContainsValue(nonDesktopElements, range, (void*)(uintptr_t)window))
        CFArrayRemoveValueAtIndex(desktopElements, i);
}

CGImageRef cgimage = CGWindowListCreateImageFromArray(CGRectInfinite, desktopElements, kCGWindowListOptionAll);
NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:cgimage];
NSData* data = [rep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:[NSDictionary dictionary]];
[data writeToFile:@"/tmp/foo.png" atomically:YES];
```

You should be able to extend the general approach to grab the Dock and menu bar. You construct a list of window IDs that you're interested in and then call `CGWindowListCreateImageFromArray()`. I compute the window IDs of the desktop elements by asking for all on-screen windows and then all on-screen windows excluding the desktop elements. The desktop elements are those in the first list which aren't in the second list.

Getting the window IDs for the menu bar and Dock is not quite as direct as that because there's no option in the CGWindowList API that directly corresponds to that.  You'll need to get the array of description dictionaries for the on-screen windows using either `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()` or `CGWindowListCreateDescriptionFromArray()` and examine the contents. The most useful key will probably be `kCGWindowLayer`. In addition to the desktop elements obtained using the technique in my sample code, I think you'll want anything at `CGWindowLevelForKey(kCGDockWindowLevelKey)` and greater.

Comment: Thank you very much! It fitted like a glove!

Comment: You're welcome.  I should mention that my sample code didn't include proper memory management.  Don't forget to `CFRelease()` the arrays and CGImage when you're done with them.  If you're not using ARC, you should also release the `NSBitmapImageRep`.

Comment: I'll remember to properly flush everything was created there :D It was a good advice!

Comment: Hi @オリバーカイル I was wondering if you completed and this and if your code was available for sharing on github or something? I am looking to do the exact same thing. :)

Comment: Hi @KenThomases I found this example here, would this also work to take a screenshot of all the contents on the screen: https://github.com/venj/Cocoa-blog-code/blob/master/Screen%20Grab/Screen%20Grab/AppDelegate.m#L30

Comment: Hi Ken I was looking for code to get all the windows in the current workspace by z order. Is this code here `CGWindowListCreate(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);` thread safe? Im crashing but not sure if its due to thread safety or some other mistake im overlooking. Thanks!