# What would be the best way to create a firefox plugin for taking desktop screenshots?

Tags: firefox-addon, screenshot

I need to create a firefox plugin that allows a user to take screenshots of any part of their desktop and have them uploaded to a server. There seems to be lots of plugins for screen capturing a webpage, but nothing for capturing anything outside of firefox. So after a little research I have not found much information on how this might be possible. I don't want to resort to a using a java applet but I will if that is my only option.

Does anyone have advice on how I might create such a feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doneskis baby check it out: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nativeshot/

Got some quirks. Released it as v1.0 though. I'm working on Android support, pretty close. I need to flesh out the editor tools. Please let me know if you're willing to collaborate.

Comment: Very cool. Sorry I have not been able to check this out in my detail our developers have been swamped working on a new major release. Hopefully we can get to looking at this soon.

Comment: Awesome @CaseyJordan I have some real cool ideas but need help with a canvas editor as I cant work on all things at once :( Im currently landing android support, then im working on a "Window Wand" feature, which expands/contracts the selection around the window clicked on, if clicking on windows side by side it exapnds to include next window, if windows not connected it deslects the previously selected and then selects the new one. :)

Comment: My goal for the canvas editor tools is like lightshot for windows: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lightshot/ but something that respects the users zoom. as the tools in lightshot are too small and there is no way to increase the tool size. also a mini window showing zoomed area for precision. would be spectacular if i could get your teams help on that.

Comment: @Casey just released v1.1 which is much smoother, i removed the console.logs so its more lightweight, im in the process of adding cloud storage services for upload. What are you developers working on? If we did collaborate what would they be interested in? I am adding some better OS compatibility too, didn't get chance to start on those canvas tools like blur, lines, arrows, text etc would be awesome if they wanted to help on that. I'm curiours what your devlopers work on, what does your company do? Firefox stuff?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a Firefox addon is the most appropriate approach here. Maybe split the task into a Firefox addon to offer the "upload to a server" component and a native app to do the desktop screenshot (or just integrate with existing screenshot tools).

If you're worried about complicating the installation process for end users, you could look into bundling the addon component and native app into a single installer (e.g. MSI on Windows, RPM on Linux, etc.). You'll have to come up with different apps for each platform you want to support (and maybe even each version - e.g. Windows XP vs Windows 10).

Whatever you decide, you'll probably need to create a more specific question to get further help here (there's no simple Firefox.Addons.API.TakeScreenShot() answer I'm afraid).

Also make sure you're using the right terminology - a plugin is the deprecated NPAPI approach whereas addons are still supported.

Comment: Thanks Lucky, I think that is the answer I was looking for. Mainly I wanted to know if it would be possible to have a desktop app talk to the firefox addon so that it can interact with the webapp in firefox. It sounds like this is possible right?

Comment: Yes that is possible. You can use some form of IPC - there are already some questions on here about IPC in Firefox addons but in brief, your options would include a file watcher or some kind of network connection over localhost. My guess is that having Firefox watch for a new file in a specific location would be enough for your case but if you want to get detailed feedback in the desktop app you might need something more complex.

Comment: Boooo! Why didn't you mention js-ctypes!! :P hahaha

Comment: Mainly because of the difficulty and likely long-term instability of targeting different libraries across multiple platforms. I have no doubt it is technically possible but I expect it's a lot more work up front and as platforms change in future compared to just linking two simpler components together via a file-based IPC. There are also probably a lot of subtleties around multiple monitors and virtual desktops that existing native screenshot tools have already solved. Either way, I don't doubt that the ctypes approach would be very technically interesting so I'm sure you'll have fun with it!

Comment: Hahah whoops missed your reply. Yeah that's a good point that existing tools already handled it so just using those tools with [MDN :: Addon SDK - system_child_process](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_child_process) is a very good recommendation. I'm just a nut and when I looked at the screenshot tools out there they were doing what I was doing for js-ctypes anyways :P weee hahaha check it out so far for [winnt and osx](#comment48454370_30109069) :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually working on taking native desktop screenshots just in the last coupel of days. I'm using js-ctypes. My work goal is the same exact thing to, upload to server. If you would like to collaborate I am very open to it! We can chat about it on #jsctypes irc channel :)  irc://moznet/jsctypes ([Mibbit IRC WebApp](https://client00.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%23jsctypes)) If you don't know js-ctypes thats ok i can handle that while you can handle uploading techniques, and an editor on canvas :) The editor is a huge part of it, you can see my ideas/plans here: https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/wiki/NativeShot

I'm really really interested in a collab on this!

I'm still working on windows right now, the color is messed up: https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/tree/digitanks-method

I was just about to start OSX work following this example here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html and here: [Take ScreenShot without Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666123/take-screenshot-without-window)

You can install the addon from that branch and click the icon that gets added to the toolbar, it will take a screenshot with 3sec delay and then append it to the body of the selected tab. (Windows only right now)

Comment: Thanks Noitidart, I will have my developers look into your projects. I think collaboration would be great. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @CaseyJordan I really look forward to hearing from them! :) And this kind of goes against what Ratty mentioned in your accepted answer, but I feel a firefox addon is an excellent approach here. No need for any IPC.